# Cerrar un programa Java en cualquier momento

Tags: java

### Duda Java

La duda que tengo es referente a como podría terminar un programa en Java en cualquier momento de la ejecución escribiendo una palabra en concreto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con `System.exit(0);`cierra la ejecución

Comment: A lo que me refiero es a que el usuario pueda terminar la ejecución del programa escribiendo una palabra en concreto, por ejemplo: _terminar_ o _cancelar_.

Comment: Simple, captura esa palabra y si coincide ejecuta lo que he puesto.

Answer (score 1):

Partyhard, bueno, aqui tienes un ejemplo de como te puedes guiar :)

por ejemplo: en un jframe genera un jtextfield y un jbutton:
y en el evento click o action del jbutton coloca esto:

```
if(jtextfield.getText().equals("SALIR")){
jframe.dispose();
}
```

y cada vez que le des click al boton, ese codigo obtendra el texto de el jtextfield y lo igualara con lo que escribiste en la evaluacion del if.  Tambien puedes hacerlo con el equalsIgnoreCase.

Saludos :d espero haberte ayudado!